# No output is produced even after putting a test case in the code

Tags: python

```
from brisa.core.reactors import install_default_reactor
reactor = install_default_reactor()


import os
import unittest

from brisa.upnp.device import Device, Service
from brisa.upnp.device.service import StateVariable


class SwitchPower(Service):

    def __init__(self):
        Service.__init__(self,
                         'SwitchPower',
                         'urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SwitchPower:1',
                         '',
                         os.getcwd() + '/SwitchPower-scpd.xml')
        self.target = False
        self.status = False


    def SetTarget(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.target = kwargs['NewTargetValue']
        self.status = self.target
        self.set_state_variable('Status', self.target)
        print 'Light switched ', {'1': 'on', '0': 'off'}.get(self.target, None)
        return {}

    def GetTarget(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'RetTargetValue': self.target}

    def soap_GetStatus(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'ResultStatus': self.status}


class BinaryLight(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.server_name = 'Binary Light device'
        self.device = None
    def _create_device(self):
        project_page = 'https://garage.maemo.org/projects/brisa'
        self.device = Device('urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1',
                            self.server_name,
                            manufacturer = 'Ankit',
                            model_name = 'Binary Light Device',
                            model_description = 'Test Device',
                            model_number = '1.0',
                            model_url=project_page)
    def _add_service(self):
        switch = SwitchPower()
        self.device.add_service(switch)
    def start(self):
        self._create_device()
        self._add_services()
        self.device.start()
        reactor.add_after_stop_func(self.device.stop)
        reactor.main()


# Here's our "unit tests".

class IsOddTests(unittest.TestCase):



    def testOne(self):

        self.failUnless(_create_device('urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1'))

        print self.failUnless(_create_device('urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1'))





def main():

    unittest.main()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = BinaryLight()
    device.start()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want tests to be run when you invoke the script, you need:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, the generally recommended practice is to put your tests in a sep. file (with the above "main"), so you can keep the main section in your existing program.